# minimize $(1/2)x^TPx+q^tx+r$ subject to $x^tx \le 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

minimize $(1/2)x^TPx+q^tx+r$ subject to $x^tx \le 1$. The usage of the Lagrangian is not allowed.

I view it as a quadratic equation minimisation task. The way I see it I should take the gradient made it equal to zero and find the optimal point $x^{*}=-P^{1/2}q$. Now we want that $|P^{-1/2}q| \le 1$. What to do next?

Comment: Is $P $ positive semi definite?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes it is. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to do this without some form of optimality condition.